# Is the PE Optional Header CheckSum field obselete now?

Tags: checksum, portable-executable

I am learning analysing pe files and I have come to the checksum in the optional headers in executable images and how it is used to check for validation of drivers and system dlls. I checked some windows binaries, and they have some value in the checksum field then I checked executables and dlls I built using visual studio msvc 22 and 19, but all contains zero in the checksum field. I then checked other binaries in software I use on windows, and they seem also to have zero in the checksum field.
I this filed is not set by msvc compiler for new executables or it is specific to Microsoft only programs ?

Answer (score 0):

The short answer is no.

From [Optional Header Windows-Specific Fields (Image Only)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/debug/pe-format#optional-header-windows-specific-fields-image-only):

> The image file checksum. The algorithm for computing the checksum is incorporated into IMAGHELP.DLL. The following are checked for validation at load time: all drivers, any DLL loaded at boot time, and any DLL that is loaded into a critical Windows process.

Then it seems to be required when loading, but it also seems to be not existed on my system.